# guessing geometric series from a partial sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

[image]

I had thought the answer would be $b$ since the graph seems to be nearing a specific value and the infinite geometric sum is defined only when $|r| < 1$. However, the answer states it is $c$. Am I wrong (if so how and why), or is the answer wrong?

Comment: If the $n$-th term is $ar^{n-1}$, then from the graph, we get $a=1$,and $2 < a+ ar <3 \implies1<r<2$. But then the shape of the graph is all wrong. So the problem is wrong, not just the answers. In other words, unless I'm missing something, none of those answers is consistent with the graph.

Comment: But if I had to choose an answer, I would choose yours, since, as you observed, it matches the end behavior.

Comment: You didn't show choice **d**. What was it?

Comment: @ It wasn't even there... Perhaps the teacher deleted it.

Comment: Whatever it was, it was probably the correct answer.

Comment: Do you think you have any idea what the correct answer might be?

Comment: A convergent series for sure. But no immediate formula for the $n$-th term comes to mind.

Comment: If it _was_ a geometric series, then, given that the first term appears to be $1$, and the limit of the partial sums appears to be about $5$, that would imply $r=??$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer was almost certainly the intended answer.  Answer (c) definitely can't be correct, since the partial sums of a geometric series with $r>1$ would be growing faster and faster, since the powers of $r$ are increasing.

[As pointed out in the comments, the exact graph shown is not actually correctly to scale to be a geometric series, so all of the answers are wrong if you assume it is drawn accurately and not just a very rough sketch.  This is probably an error of laziness on the part of whoever wrote the problem: they just drew a graph of roughly the shape they wanted, without checking whether it actually numerically worked.]